# Creating snapshot of array item and compare it to the changed array SWIFT iBeacons

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, ibeacon

I've been penalised in the past for asking questions badly, and this is (for me) a complicated one to explain but here goes:

I have an array of iBeacons (knownBeacons) of which index 0 is the physically closest beacon.

The nature of beacons means that sometimes the item at index 0 changes temporarily even though nothing has physically moved.

If the item at index 0 does change without any beacons moving, it is only ever for a maximum of 2-3 loops of the function, and then it reverts back to normal.

I'd like to take a snapshot of the array as it is initialised, and use that as my working data. If the item at index 0 of the array changes, continue using the snapshot. If the new item at index 0 remains there for more than three loops of the function, take a new snapshot, and use that as the new working data.

Here is the function i'm talking about, and any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated:

```
let colours = [
    1: UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 1, alpha: 1),
    2: UIColor(red: 0, green: 1, blue: 0, alpha: 1)]
let tableNo = [
    1: "Marks Desk",
    2: "Daves Desk"]

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didRangeBeacons beacons: [AnyObject]!, inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion!) {

    //filter out any beacons with unknown location
    let knownBeacons = beacons.filter{ $0.proximity != CLProximity.Unknown }

    //Make sure there is at least one beacon available
    if(knownBeacons.count > 0){
        let closestBeacon = knownBeacons[0] as CLBeacon
        self.tableLabel.text = self.tableNo[closestBeacon.minor.integerValue]
        self.colourBar.backgroundColor = colours[closestBeacon.minor.integerValue]
    }else{
        self.tableLabel.text = "Unknown Desk"
        self.colourBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what have you tried already that doesn't work?

Comment: I'm stumped, I don't know how to even start approaching the problem, so I'm looking for some guidance

Comment: PS. I'm not looking for somebody to necessarily write the code for me, I just need some advice, like how to go about initialising the snapshot array only once and keeping it static until certain conditions are met. All my efforts are seeing to it that the array is reinitialised every time the function runs.